# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when assigning a simple bool

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am new to iOS. I am trying to set a bool in a view controller in the prepareforsegue method that leads to that view controller. When I try to to set the bool, i get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. What can I do to fix this problem?

```
   addBookViewController  *addViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
   Book *temp = [self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
   addViewController.book = temp;
   *addViewController.editMode=YES; //EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code =0, address=0x0)
```

here is the header file for the destination view controller:

```
   @interface addBookViewController : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
    @property (strong, nonatomic) Book *book;
    @property (assign) BOOL *editMode;
    @end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BOOL` is not an object type, it's a primitive (scalar). You don't need pointers to it. Change

```
@property (assign) BOOL *editMode;
```

into

```
@property (assign) BOOL editMode;
```

and also change

```
*addViewController.editMode=YES;
```

to

```
addViewController.editMode=YES;
```

and please read a tutorial on C pointers.

Answer (score 1):

BOOL isn't a class, it's a simple type like int or float. Get rid of the asterisk.

Comment: See H2CO3's answer for more complete details. You need to get rid of both asterisks.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
*addViewController.editMode=YES;
```

it should be

```
addViewController.editMode=YES;
```

also not

```
@property (assign) BOOL *editMode;
```

but

```
@property (readwrite,assign) BOOL editMode;
```

Answer (score 0):

BOOL is not an object, so you cant define yes/no for pointer.

Comment: Actually, when appropriate, it is perfectly acceptable to define a pointer to BOOL or other simple type. But not in this case.